# Add custom columns for yAxis in highcharts gantt

Tags: highcharts

I've implemented a chart like [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/meysamm22/grcxefm8/1/) with **treegrid type for its yAxis**, I want to add some columns which are shown in [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/gantt/demo/resource-management) to my chart. Indeed, I know it's easy to implement with `category` type for yAxis, but my case has nested (more than 3 levels) points.

Comment: I am afraid that this functionality is not implemented yet in the Highcharts Gantt. Please take a look: https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/39780268-multiple-collpasible-treegrid-gantt-yaxis

Comment: @SebastianWędzel Thanks for your answer, It seems to me that it's a kind of essential feature which should be implemented soonly.